# How do hide latitude and longitude from pin on google map

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview, marker

I use the following code to show location on default google maps application , but the pointer on the map is showing the latitude and logitude values which I dont want .. Also would it be possible to drop a custom pin on the default google maps app ?

```
            String uriBegin = "geo:" + Latitude + "," + Longitude;
            String query =Latitude + "," + Longitude ;
            String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
            String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
            //String uriString = "?q=" + encodedQuery ;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you check [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps)

You will find:

> geo:0,0?q=lat,lng(label) Show the map at the given longitude and
>   latitude with a string label. Example:
>   "geo:0,0?q=34.99,-106.61(Treasure)"

P.S. I don't think you can use a custom marker inside Google maps application.

```
        String uriBegin = "geo:" + Latitude + "," + Longitude;
        String query =Latitude + "," + Longitude ;
        String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
        String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "(Anylabelyouwant)" + "&z=16";
        //String uriString = "?q=" + encodedQuery ;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work !! It showed the lat and longitude values instead of just showing just label